# How do regex objects work in Python loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, if-statement

I am constructing an if statement on Python that prints something when regex's match function founds a coincidence. I would like to know why the if statement works when my statement's condition is not a boolean (I think so).

```
import re

coincidence = re.match(r'\w{3}', 'abc')

if coincidence:
  print('There\'s a match')
```

which yields:

```
"There's a match"
```

Why does it work?

Comment: There is no "if loop". `if` does not loop.

Comment: You're right. I'll change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a match is found using `re.match()` a `re.match()` object is returned. In your case this is;

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='abc'>
```

This means that the variable `coincidence` has a value that when cast by `bool()` returns `True`

```
bool(coincidence)
True
```

If a match is not found, `None` is returned, which always equates to `False`;

```
coincidence = re.match(r'\w{5}', 'abc')
print(coincidence)
#None
bool(coincidence)
#False
```

Your statement boils down to `is coincidence True`, which when returning an object it is equal to `True`.

Comment: Nice explanation. If I understand correctly, the if statement's argument is type cast to a bool, which is the key to the original question.

Comment: The coercion to boolean occurs only in `if` statements. Otherwise, you need `bool`. E.g. `bool(coincidence) is True` will return `True` when `coincidence` is not null-type.

Answer (score 3):

Python types have a "truthiness" value associated. You can try it out by executing `bool()` on different objects. The most obvious example would be integers:

```
bool(1)

> True

bool(0)

> False
```

but it goes beyond. `bool("")` will be `False`, while any other non-empty string will be `True`. Empty lists, dicts, tuples are `False`, but turn to `True` as soon as they are not empty. This is determined by the `__bool__` class method, which dictates what should be evaluated whenever `bool()` is called on the object.

In the case of the output of the `re.match` function, it will either return `None` if it doesn't find the pattern (which evaluates to `False`), or a `re.Match` object (which evaluates to `True`).

That's why in your case, since the pattern is found sucessfully, the condition of the if clause evaluates to True.